# What's the difference between the term 'Device' and 'Machine'?

Tags: terminology, device, electric-machine

Limiting the question only to the electrical domain. Calling AC machines as ac device mean the same or there is a difference in the terminology.

Comment: Transformers are used to used to convert electrical energy (step up and step down). They are static in nature and does the conversion by changing electrical parameter. They do not do the conversion between Electrical to mechanical energy. So, is transformer a device or machine ?

Comment: This is a question of English language - the distinction you are looking for does not really exist since the words are far older than the technology.

Answer (score 2):

The term "AC machine" is used to describe machines which convert electrical energy into mechanical energy (the contrary is also true).
While the term "AC device" designate anything working with alternative current.

I'm not a native english but that's what I understand.

Answer (score 1):

Devices are things like switches, relays, circuit breakers, transducers etc. that do not, as a primary function, convert energy between electrical and mechanical. A motor could be called a device if it is used to perform a small task as part of the overall function of a machine or appliance. The term "electric machine" is most often used when both the motoring mode and the generating mode are of interest. In most contexts, the specific type and function of the machine is used,  DC motor or synchronous generator for example.

Like a lot of terminology, context, geographical region and other factors play a large part in usage. How terms should used is largely a matter of custom and opinion.

Comment: "The term "electric machine" is most often used when both the motoring mode and the generating mode are of interest."

Comment: But we call transformer as a AC Machine rather a device.

Comment: Transformers are classified as AC machines for the purpose of study because the study of transformer provides some of the necessary foundation for studying the properties of motors and generators. Strictly speaking, they are not machines and not referred to as machines in most contexts.

Comment: Small transformers are often called components or devices. Large transformers that have active cooling systems, instrumentation and protective devices built into them would likely be called apparatus items.